# Redirect Internet Explorer 8 and below to different Website

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, redirect, internet-explorer-8

I would like to redirect users using Internet Explorer 8 and below to a different website (i.e www.google.com)

I found the java code below from here: [http://www.daobydesign.com/blog/tips/css-html/detect-redirect-script-for-internet-explorer-ie/](http://netrenderer.com/)

And modified it to Internet Explorer 8 as shown below, however it is not working.

```
<!--
var browser = navigator.appName
var ver = navigator.appVersion
var thestart = parseFloat(ver.indexOf("MSIE"))+1
var brow_ver = parseFloat(ver.substring(thestart+4,thestart+8))
if ((browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") && (brow_ver < 8))
{
window.location="http://www.google.com/";
}
//-->
```

I tested my site here: [Browser Render Website](http://netrenderer.com/)

My website is [My Website](http://www.rapidevac.biz/ca/) java script redirect works for internet explorer 6 and 7 but not 8. How can I include i.e.8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

See the line `if ((browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") && (brow_ver < 8))` ? The last piece is saying that the browser version must be less than eight for the code to run. You want less than nine. So, `if ((browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") && (brow_ver < 9))`